# How does this log method work in a .NET application?

Tags: c#, .net

I am working on a **.NET** project using **C#** and I have the following doubt.

I have this method that write some error information into a **.log** file in a specific directory on my file system:

```
private static void writeErrorLog(string error)
{
    string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
    string currDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    System.IO.File.AppendAllText(currDir + "\\FILE\\LOG\\Error_" + date + ".txt", error);
}
```

Ok this **writeErrorLog()** method will be called into some **try catch** block of my code, something like this:

```
try
{
    currentAttachmentFileData = currentAttachmentFile.OpenBinary();
    currentAttachementModel = new AttachmentModel(currentAttachment, currentAttachmentFileData);
    attachmentsModelList.Add(currentAttachementModel);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //writeLog(2, String.Format("Unable to read the attachment, it may be corrupted {0} - {1}", fileName, ex.Message));
    writeErrorLog("Errore inserimento attachment. Numero protocollo: " + recNumber 
                + " Data protocollo: " + recDate 
                + " Nome attachment: " +  currentAttachmentFile 
                + " INFO: " + ex.ToString() + " | " + ex.Message + " | " + ex.StackTrace);


}
```

It happens in different places of my code.

My doubt is: the file is the same, so it means that it will be added a new line to this file every time that an error occours.

Is it my reasnong correct?

Comment: what kind of application is this? Concurrent access to log file should be handled

Comment: Why are you writing your own logging code? There are frameworks out there that do this for you, I strongly advise using them over a custom solution. For example, what happens if this log method is called by 2 threads at the same time?

Comment: not exactly correct, dateformat in the filename of the log will propably generate a new file on almost every call. also you should look at logging in .net, there are many solutions so you don't have to reinvent the wheel

Comment: You date will have a different value every time the log is written. So it creates a new file every time. `File.AppendAllText` will append the specified string to the file, creating the file if it does not already exist. You want `string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");` to create a new log file every day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file name is `string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");` so it changes every second.

You should definitely add some abstraction here and hide `writeErrorLog` behind an interface. Behind the interface you could have your own implementation of `writeErrorLog`, but as others suggested I would strongly recommend using libs over your custom solution.

More on available libraries:

- [benchmarking-5-popular-net-logging-libraries](https://www.loggly.com/blog/benchmarking-5-popular-net-logging-libraries/)
- [dotnetlogging.com](http://www.dotnetlogging.com/)